# how the mapping of script attribute text/some-library works

Tags: javascript, babeljs

How the browser knows which javascript library to run or for transpiling, how the connection and mapping is made, for instance in the following code how the browser knows that it has to use Babel for the type ***text/babel***.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

It's basically an understanding towards on how can I create my own custom script types and associated js libraries for script parsing or transpiling.

Comment: The browser doesn't understand the script so  it will just be ignored by the browser. The embedded Babel-JavaScript file will search for scripts with the type `text/babel` and transpile and execute it manually. `text/babel` isn't a official MIME-type so the browser itself doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I see. `transpile and execute it manually`, you mean once transpiling it injects the compiled code dynamically in a new script tag?

Comment: I didn't check the Babel source code but they probably use `eval()` to execute the transpiled result script. I think theres no other way to execute JS without an external JavaScript file.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. You can also execute JS without `eval` by creating the script element and setting its content like following: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmEOGj?editors=0010